# Dynamic SQL with SSIS OLE DB Command

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a table which stores a list of rows that were deleted from the source database so that this deletion can be mirrored in the target database. I have a Data Flow set up which takes this list with the following items:

Table Name | Primary Key Name | Primary Key Value

For each row in this table, I want to execute a SQL statement against my target db, which looks like this:

`DELETE FROM ? WHERE ? = ?`

I've added a OLE DB Command with this as the command text, however, when I go to map the "Available Destination Columns", none are listed. What workarounds are available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a variable and use an expression to build the SQL dynamically, then use that variable as the source for your OLE DB Command.

Comment: I need this to run on a per-row basis. Would a variable expression support this?

Comment: If you load the rowset into an SSIS variable of type object then use a For-Each task to iterate through each row in the object (ADO.Net dataset) then yes that'll work fine. Here's an example: http://pldineshtech.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/loop-through-each-row-in-table-using.html. It does highlight a possible design flaw, i.e. RBAR. For example an alternative to this method is to load your change log into a table in the target and do a bulk update/insert instead. This will be much faster but possibly trickier.

Comment: Are all of your primary keys in one column only? Allowing for composite primary keys might be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I think for something like this you will be better off using an `Script Component` to perform the operations. The `OLD DB Command` isn't going to handle the dynamic table part.